# Why does Rash"i seem bored frequently?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It seems that often Rash"i needs to explain a word in another language, he says *blahs" afterwards. An example:

Rashi on Genesis 1:2:

**תהו** אשטורדי"שון בְּלַעַ"ז:

תהו is *estordison* - Blahs.

Why does Rash"i seem so bored when he does that?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Why does he seem bored when he does that? Because that's how you're interpreting "blahs", I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Rashi was enlisted by [King John the Posthumous](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_I_of_France) (Don't trust Wikipedia's chronology) on Tisha B'av, 1025, to keep Old French alive. This mundane task led him to extreme boredom, and even more so, took away his time from Torah writings. As such, many things were left tragically unexplained and lost to Klal Yisrael. It is in this vein that we learn that one of Tisha B'Av's tragedies is:

> שרף אפוסטומוס את התורה
>
> (King John the) Posthumous burnt (ie. destroyed) the Torah.